# Binding CORBA object to Weblogic 11g not working

Tags: java, jndi, corba

I have written server side code to bind `CORBA` object to `Weblogic 11g`.
Have created context factory and binding ORB reference from servant.
Its getting bound to JNDI tree , but while doing lookup from client its giving error as

> "java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: The object identified by: '257' could not be found"

Answer (score 0):

[vaibhav singh](https://plus.google.com/113215864381857458120)  has solved the issue by following procedure:

### Root Cause Analysis:

The startup options was containing JVM arguments `"-Dweblogic.management.server=t3://10.188.103.55:7002"`. The admin server should not contain this, as it makes the server to run in managed server mode. So the thing was admin server was starting as managed server, and trying to contact itself, creating a deadlock kind scenario.

Usually `${ADMIN_URL}` sets up the variable `"weblogic.management.server"`. I tried to find out that who set this varible in this condition, as setDomain.sh script stricts that this variable is null for admin server startup. On little debugging on environment it was clear `${JAVA_OPTS}` was exported in the UNIX session, as one can also see in startup the variables are repeated. So the crux of matter was I restarted one managed server which exported `JAVA_OPTS` variable in the session and when I restarted admin server, it appended its options in already exported `JAVA_OPTS` but not clearing it.

### Solution:

1. Either manually purge the startup variables from UNIX, Linux session if you are stubborn and don't want to close your session.
2. Kill the UNIX Linux session. Start a new session, it will automatically purge the exported variables. Now start your admin server.

### Resource Link:

Full Details is described here: [Caused by: java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: The object identified by: '31' could not be found.  Either it was has not been exported or it has been collected by the distributed garbage collector.](http://wlsfromme.blogspot.com/2014/01/the-object-identified-by-31-could-not.html)

Comment: I am running admin server using startWeblogic.cmd on windows.and object identification id is '257'.